# .htaccess redirect if file or second level directory doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a situation where I have a bunch of old content in a /products directory. Moving forward, new content is going in a /product folder. What I would like to do is redirect to /product if a file, or directory doesn't exist.

I have the following in a .htaccess file in the /products folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ /product/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works well for files in the /products directory and sub directories that contain index.htm files or other file names, however I'd like to limit a redirect on a non existing directory to be 2 levels:

**/products/someproduct** - Do not redirect

**/products/someproduct/anotherproduct**
If it doesn't exist, redirect to /product/someproduct/anotherproduct

How do I force the rule to only apply to sub directories that are 2 levels or more deep?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#for all /products/somefolder/any_folder_level_deeep content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products/([^/]+/.+)$ [NC]
#if file does not exist
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#and directory does not exist
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#redirect to product folder
RewriteRule   . /product/%1 [R=301,L]
```